# Filter posts in category archive page by year using a dropdown

Tags: wp-query, filters, query, archive-template

I'm trying to filter my posts by year in different categories by changing the query using a dropdown with this code:

```
                <form method="post" action="">
                    <select id="year" name="year" onchange='this.form.submit();'>
                        <option value="2019">2019</option>
                        <option value="2018">2018</option>
                        <option value="2017">2017</option>
                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                        <option value="2015">2015</option>
                    </select>
                </form>

                <div id="categories">
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Select category' ); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
            function onCatChange() {
                if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
                    location.href = "<?php if(pll_current_language == "en"){
                        echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); } else { echo esc_url('beta.dev/');} ?>?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
                }
            }
            dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
            -->
        </script>
    </div>

    <ul>

    <?php query_posts('year=' . $_POST['year'] ); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <li><p class="post-info"><?php the_date(); ?> | <?php $categories = get_the_category();

     if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
         echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
     } ?></p></li>
    <?php 
    endwhile; else :
    ?>
        <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata() ?>
    </ul>

    </div>
    </section>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The category part is working properly, and shows posts from the chosen category. However, changing the year instead redirects me to my custom index.php in my template, can someone point me in the right direction? Would love some feedback/help!

Regards

Comment: You should use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) & not query_posts for pretty much all custom queries you do. Also, variables in the url are `$_GET` not `$_POST`.

Comment: What file have you put that code in? Why don’t you use native archive mechanisms for that?